# Is there api for ripple.com to authentificate with username & password?

Tags: ripple

I'm googling, and looking for such option, to authenticate to ripple.com with out secret key, but username and password.

I've found only with secret key:

```
# curl -X POST -d '{ "method" : "sign", "params" : [ { "secret" : "snoPBrXtMeMyMHUVTgbuqAfg1SUTb", "tx_json" : {"TransactionType":"Payment",  "Account":"rHb9CJAWyB4rj91VRWn96DkukG4bwdtyTh", "Amount":"200000000", "Destination":"r3kmLJN5D28dHuH8vZNUZpMC43pEHpaocV" }} ] }' http://s1.ripple.com:51234
```

How properly to authenticate with username and password only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usernames and passwords are client wallet functions. They have no meaning to the Ripple network and servers would have no idea what to do with them.

In fact, servers do not have permission to obtain encrypted wallets because if they did, they could attempt to brute force decrypt them, negating the security advantages of the blob vault. By design, is is as difficult as possible to ask someone else to obtain your wallet, purportedly on your behalf. This is necessary to prevent malicious web sites from sending javascript to your browser that causes it to brute force other people's wallets as you browse the Internet.

Answer (score 1):

Ripple.com does not store any information about the users of the ripple network. Instead if you want to make transactions using only a username and password you must store your secret key in an encrypted blob vault, using your username and password credentials to create the encrypted cypher-text.

The web wallet app available at ripple.com/client uses such a blob vault to store and retrieve your ripple secret key. Then behind the scenes it signs transactions to the ripple network using your key. The provider of your vault is configurable and if you desire you may implement your own blob vault by following the vault protocol and by consulting the official open source [blob vault code on github](https://github.com/ripple/ripple-blobvault).

Of course in your own ripple applications you can use whichever protocol you like to store and retrieve your secret key using a username and password for encryption. Remember it is not possible to make transactions in the ripple ledger without a signature from your account secret key.